# Migrate from AEM CRX to a standalone JackRabbit OAK repository

Tags: jackrabbit-oak

We are currently using AEM 6.5 with CRX / JackRabbit OAK 1.2.12

I read link [https://medium.com/@anmolbhardwaj94/17-5-things-jcr-jackrabbit-oak-d2b91d256330#:~:text=CRX%20was%20based%20on%20Apache,and%20scalable%20Apache%20Jackrabbit%20Oak.](https://medium.com/@anmolbhardwaj94/17-5-things-jcr-jackrabbit-oak-d2b91d256330#:%7E:text=CRX%20was%20based%20on%20Apache,and%20scalable%20Apache%20Jackrabbit%20Oak.), based on that information it seems that AEM CRX is JackRabbit AOK.

Why I need to know this is: Can we migrate from this CRX 1 on 1 to a standalone JackRabbit OAK repository?

I read documentation about AEM CRX and JAckRabbit OAK but couldn't find the right answer.